# RFID + LCD + Arduino Mega 2560 = RFID not printing correctly

Tags: lcd, rfid

My Arduino Mega isn't printing the RFID card's tag it simply prints the card's 2 digits at a time but deletes the previous prints. Can I get help with this?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

Servo myservo;  //creates servo to control

const int rs = 26, en = 27, d4 = 28, d5 = 29, d6 = 31, d7 = 30;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

#define SS_PIN 53
#define RST_PIN 5
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.
int R=3;
int G=8;
int B=6;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522
  Serial.println("Approximate your card to the reader...");
  lcd.print("Place your card");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Near reader");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  myservo.attach(7);//attatches servo to pin 7
  myservo.write(179);
}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(B, 255);
  // Look for new cards
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.print("UID tag :");
  byte letter;
  String content= "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
     lcd.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
     lcd.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
     lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  }
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "4F 60 3C D9") {
    //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
    Serial.println("Authorized access");
    lcd.print("Authorized");
    analogWrite(B, 0);
    tone(4, 900, 100);
    lcd.clear();
    Serial.println("Unlocking...");
    lcd.print("Unlocking...");
    lcd.clear();
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    analogWrite(G, 127);
    delay(1000);
    myservo.write(100);
    delay(15);
    Serial.println("Unlocked");
    lcd.print("Unlocked");
    lcd.clear();
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    analogWrite(G, 255);
    delay(5000);
    Serial.println("Relocking...");
    lcd.print("Relocking...");
    lcd.clear();
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    analogWrite(G, 127);
    delay(1000);
    myservo.write(179);
    delay(15);
    Serial.println("Locked");
    lcd.print("Locked");
    lcd.clear();
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    analogWrite(G, 0);
    delay(100); 
  } else {
    Serial.println("Checking Card");
    lcd.print("Checking Card");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    delay(100);
    lcd.clear();
    Serial.println("Access denied");
    lcd.print("Access denied");
    analogWrite(B, 0);
    tone(4, 900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 1900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 1900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 1900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 1900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 1900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(100);
  }
 lcd.clear();
 Serial.println("Ready");
 lcd.print("Ready");
}
```

Comment: you did not give a clear explanation ... what does this mean? `deletes the previous prints`

Comment: What it would do is display the two hexadecimal digits in rapid succession and only see the last two for a split second

Comment: still not a clear explanation ... are you talking about LCD or serial monitor window on your computer? ... you are sending data to both of those, and both of those can exhibit the behaviour that you describe

Comment: it is my lcd that is not doing what i want it to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i fixed it. It is now this :

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


Servo myservo;  //creates servo to control

const int rs = 44, en = 45, d4 = 46, d5 = 47, d6 = 49, d7 = 48;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

#define SS_PIN 53
#define RST_PIN 5
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.
int R=3;
int G=8;
int B=6;

void setup() 
{
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522
  Serial.println("Place your card near reader");
  lcd.print("Place your card");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Near reader");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  myservo.attach(7);//attatches servo to pin 7
  myservo.write(179);
}
void loop() 
{
  analogWrite(B, 255);
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  lcd.clear();
  Serial.print("UID tag :");
  lcd.print("ID:");
  byte letter;
  String content= "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++)
  {
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
     lcd.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
     lcd.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "4F 60 3C D9") //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
  {
    delay(5000);
    lcd.clear();
    Serial.println("Scanning Database");
    lcd.print("Scanning");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Database");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    delay(5000);
    lcd.clear();
    Serial.println("Authorized access");
     lcd.print("Authorized");
    analogWrite(B, 0);
    tone(4, 900, 100);
    lcd.clear();
    Serial.println("Unlocking...");
    lcd.print("Unlocking...");
    lcd.clear();
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    analogWrite(G, 127);
    delay(1000);
    myservo.write(100);
    delay(15);
    Serial.println("Unlocked");
    lcd.print("Unlocked");
    delay(5000);
    lcd.clear();
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    analogWrite(G, 255);
    Serial.println("Relocking...");
    lcd.print("Relocking...");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    analogWrite(G, 127);
    myservo.write(179);
    delay(15);
    Serial.println("Locked");
    lcd.print("Locked");
    delay(100); 
    lcd.clear();
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    analogWrite(G, 0);
  }else{
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
    Serial.println("Scanning Database");
    lcd.print("Scanning Databas");
    delay(5000);
    lcd.clear();
    Serial.println("Access denied");
    lcd.print("Access denied");
    analogWrite(B, 0);
    tone(4, 900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 1900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 1900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 1900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 1900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(500);
    tone(4, 1900, 1000);
    analogWrite(R, 255);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(R, 0);
    delay(100);
  }
 lcd.clear();
 Serial.println("Ready");
 lcd.print("Ready");
}
```

had to remove the `lcd.setCursor(0, 1);`
from line 57.